# Can I change my address to other country from US, my case is at NVC

Tags: usa, visa, us-citizens, family, dependent-visa

I'm F2B category applicant and my case is just landed at NVC and I want to change postal address, as my parents changed address two times after they applied and now they're quite old, so my questions are

- Will I receive letter on my postal address, which I received email (Notice of Immigrant Visa Case Creation) ?
- Can I change address to another country like to give address my current location India(https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/national-visa-center/immigrant-visas-processing-general-faqs.html).
- Can I start process and to pay fee online portal https://ceac.state.gov/IV (by adding Case number and invoice number) or should I wait for letter from NVC ?
- Can I update my father's phone number to my phone number(India cell number) ?

Looking for your response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing your address to outside the USA could signal that you're abandoning your residency in the USA or that you don't live in the USA at all.

It may be safer to either rent a Post Office Box or Private Mail Box. There are some private mail box services that will even open and scan your mail for you - and send the scanned images anywhere in the country. Some googling will find them for you.

Or to be absolutely sure, you can have the correspondence sent to your immigration attorney. You may be able to find an attorney who is reasonably priced.

For your phone number, you could use the free google voice service to get a USA phone number that will forward to your gmail account.